# Where to find the .sqlite file in IOS7

Tags: iphone, sqlite

Hi,

In my application I'm using the sqlite3 database and I'm storing the data in the database. But the problem is -- where I can find the .sqlite file in my project? I can't find any .sqlite file inside my project. Please tell me where it will be stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be in the Documents directory in the application sandbox:

```
/Users/<Username>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/<YourAppGUID>/Documents
```

It will not be generated inside your project bundle.

Comment: i using the sqlite for the first time i have seached in the doucments the folder called users dose's t exit in documents and pls tell me what is appguid which id ihave to give in this place

Comment: This is not the Documents folder in your mac. Go to Finder and press Shift+Cmd+G and paste /Users/<Username>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/ in there. It will take you to the iOS 7 directory. There you will find the list of big alphanumeric numbers as folder names.
P.S. Make sure you replace <Username> in the above string with your machine user name.

Comment: /Users/madhavadudipalli/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/ this url is its coming can't found the folder

Comment: Try navigating to /Users/madhavadudipalli/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/ and then select the folder with correct version number. May be you are using something other than 7.0 -- like 7.0 64bit or something